# Is possible to remove X-Frame-Options header from JS in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to remove **x-frame-options** with javascript in my chrome extension?

Currently I have this

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "background",
  "description": "DE background",
  "version": "1.0",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.web.com/*"],
      "js": ["contentscript.js"],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["*://*.web.com/*", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking"]
}
```

**Background.js**

```
// This is to remove X-Frame-Options header, if present
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    function(info) {
      var headers = info.responseHeaders;
      var index = headers.findIndex(x=>x.name.toLowerCase() == "x-frame-options");
      if (index !=-1) {
        headers.splice(index, 1);
      }
      return {responseHeaders: headers};
    },
    {
        urls: ['*://*.web.com/*'], //
        types: ['sub_frame']
    },
    ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']
);
```

**contentscript.js**

```
var elementToInsert = document.createElement("h1");
elementToInsert.textContent = "This text comes from my content script.";
document.body.insertBefore(elementToInsert, document.body.firstChild);
```

This works fine if the code is in background.js, but, it is possible to add that code (background.js) in contentscript.js?

I ask this question, because I currently have my extension in the chrome store with other manifest.json and background.js, but I just want to edit contentscript.js for to remove x-frame-options, I do not want to edit Background.js or manifest.json  Only contentscript.js

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you're almost there. Just [declare the background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) in manifest.json. In a content script chrome.webRequest won't work.

Comment: is it not possible to add the code in the contentscript.js?

Comment: No, it won't work.